# how to start An Activity using a sample class?

Tags: android, android-context

I would like to start my Activity using a simple class. I know that I ought to use Context().

I tried

```
private static Context context;
.
.
.
      Intent intent = new Intent(); 
      intent.setClass(context, UpdateCatalog.class);

      startActivity(intent);
```

but the intent is unkown in a simple class and known in an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must import your class.

```
import your.package.YourClass;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
```

Second, use this for launch your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //if your Main class extends Activity
    Context context = this; 

    Button anButton = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.anButton);

    anButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
                StartActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `context` is a `Context`, then call `startActivity()` on `context`.

Comment: private static Context context;

Comment: Can you give me an example. please

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent)`. `startActivity()` is a method, a method is called on a variable

Comment: @Zizou: Do not a `Context` in a static data member, as you are most likely introducing a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass context to you SimpleClass. For example:

```
public class MyAct extends Activity {
....
    //Pass link to activity (context's descendant) to your class
    SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass(this)
}
```

Then inside SimpleClass you have to do this:

```
private Context context;
//Constructor that receives context instance
public SimpleClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

//Method to start new activity
private void startUpdateCatalogActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateCatalog.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```